# .NET Session expires in Chrome, but not IE

Tags: .net, google-chrome, internet-explorer

We have a customer who has an Ipsec tunnel to a third party. This third party is hosting a .NET application. Obviously, I don’t have any access to the configuration of that.
For a couple of weeks now, our customer has experienced troubles with this application. He frequently gets notifications that the session has expired and he is forced to log in again. Interestingly, this only happens when he’s using Google Chrome or Edge. With Internet Explorer, everything works fine.
The provider of the application isn’t very helpful – he’s just telling me that Google Chrome is working fine for him.
So, my question is: Is there a difference in session handling in Chrome and Internet Explorer? Are there some Chrome Settings I could adjust?

Comment: I searched and found [this article](https://www.petefreitag.com/item/857.cfm) talking about difference in session handling in Chrome and IE. But it works well on the provider's Chrome, so I suggest that you can ask your customer to try the app in Chrome incognito window or disable all Chrome extensions, clear browser cache and try again.

Answer (score 0):

By default Asp.Net session varible uses cookies to store session ID. Do you have cookies enabled in the Chrome?

Comment: Yes, cookies are enabled. But I can't see any cookies from this application (in chrome and in IE)